# Fsunit returns runtime generated actual value

Tags: unit-testing, f#, fsunit

We are using F# for our HTTP calls automation tests and I stumbled upon one runtime error from FsUnit that I am not sure I understand, I admit I wrote F# only 2 times in my life therefore this might be stupid question but bear with me.

This is the test:

```
[<Test>]
[<AsyncStateMachine(typeof<Task>)>]
member x.``When all dependent microservices and kafka are up and running service should be healty``() = toTask <| async {
    let! responseContent = Http.AsyncRequestString(url = config.ApiHost + "/BetsReportingApiModule/healthcheck")
    let expectedIsAlive = JsonValue.Parse(responseContent).GetProperty("alive").AsBoolean
    return  expectedIsAlive |> should be True
}
```

And this is the error message:

> Message:   Expected: True
>     But was:  **<< StartupCode$SBTech-BetsReportingAPI-AutomationTests>.$HttpApiTests+expectedIsAlive@1689>**

I can guess that this is some runtime generated string but I am not sure what is the cause if it.

Comment: I suppose the `AsBoolean` is method not property

Comment: @FoggyFinder, thanks I guess autocomplete failed me, whats more in C# always first parameter of `Assert` is expected while here it looks like to be other way around which also helped to my confusion, thanks.

Comment: Try using the FsUnitTyped namespace instead of FsUnit, it can catch problems like that at compile time.